# Treeview Bindings Not Showing Second level

Tags: wpf, xaml

Hello I have a treeview that I am trying to diplay 2 levels deep.

The second level is not displaying

Here is the class and Collection from my VM

```
public class BuildTree
{
   public int Id { get; set; } 
   public string Groups { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<myAreas> Areas { get; set; }               
}                       
//Areas has a name property I want to show on the second level under the group

public ObservableCollection<BuildTree> MyObsvCollection
{
    get { return _myCollection; }
}
```

Here is my Xaml

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyObsvCollection}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Groups}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Areas}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` has no items to display. You should move `ItemsSource` to outer `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and then `ItemTemplate` can be simple `DataTemplate`

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Areas}">
    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Groups}" />
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```